# CloudWatch Metrics for Volume IOPS, Volume Throughput (MiB/s) and Network (Gbps)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ebs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I had to troubleshoot one application at AWS and was not easy to use all CloudWatch Metrics Graphs to interpret environment healthiness, so I decided to share my experience here.

CloudWatch give us metrics for CPU, Memory*, Disk and Network.

> * to get memory metrics you need to install CloudWatch Agent.

CPU and Memory give us the metric in percentage, which is clear ans strait-forward to interpret.
But Disk and Network are not that easy, for example I would like to check IOPS and Throughput (MiB/s) for my volumes and Network (Gbps).

I needed those values because AWS define EBS limits as IOPS and Throughput (MB/s) and Instance network limit as Gbps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Total IOPS**
EBS Volume give us metrics `VolumeReadOps` and `VolumeWriteOps`. Let me quote AWS documentation.

> `VolumeReadOps` - The total number of read operations in a specified period of time.
> To calculate the average read operations per second (read IOPS) for the period, divide the total read operations in the period by the number of seconds in that period.
>
> `VolumeWriteOps` - The total number of write operations in a specified period of time.
> To calculate the average write operations per second (write IOPS) for the period, divide the total write operations in the period by the number of seconds in that period.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using_cloudwatch_ebs.html

To get the Total IOPS we need to `(VolumeReadOps + VolumeWriteOps) / SecondsInPeriod`.
Luckily CloudWatch help us with `Expression`. Use the expression below, the function `PERIOD` is our friend here.

```
m1 = VolumeWriteOps - Sum
m2 = VolumeReadOps - Sum
Expression: (m1+m2)/PERIOD(m1)
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html

---

**Total Throughput (MiB/s)**
EBS Volume give us metrics `VolumeReadBytes` and `VolumeWriteBytes`. Let me quote AWS documentation.

> `VolumeReadBytes` - Provides information on the read operations in a specified period of time. The `Sum` statistic reports the total number of bytes transferred during the period.
>
> `VolumeWriteBytes` - Provides information on the write operations in a specified period of time. The `Sum` statistic reports the total number of bytes transferred during the period.

Both metrics give us the value in `bytes`, but we want them in `MiB`, so to convert we need to divide by `1048576`, which is the result of `1024 * 1024`. Let me explain in detail.

```
1024 bytes = 1 KiB
1024 KiB = 1 MiB
```

To get the Total Throughput in `MiB/s` we need to `((VolumeReadBytes + VolumeWriteBytes) / 1048576) / SecondsInPeriod`.
Use the expression below, the function `PERIOD` is our friend here.

```
m1 = VolumeWriteBytes - Sum
m2 = VolumeReadBytes - Sum
Expression: ((m1+m2)/1048576)/PERIOD(m1)
```

---

**Total Network (Gbps)**
EC2 Instance give us metrics `NetworkIn` and `NetworkOut`. Let me quote AWS documentation.

> `NetworkIn` - The number of bytes received on all network interfaces by the instance. This metric identifies the volume of incoming network traffic to a single instance.
> The number reported is the number of bytes received during the period. If you are using basic (five-minute) monitoring, you can divide this number by 300 to find Bytes/second. If you have detailed (one-minute) monitoring, divide it by 60.
>
> `NetworkOut` - The number of bytes sent out on all network interfaces by the instance. This metric identifies the volume of outgoing network traffic from a single instance.
> The number reported is the number of bytes sent during the period. If you are using basic (five-minute) monitoring, you can divide this number by 300 to find Bytes/second. If you have detailed (one-minute) monitoring, divide it by 60.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html

Both metrics give us the value in `bytes per period`, but we want them in `gigabits / second`.
To convert from "period" to "second" we just need to divide by `300` (as I am using standard monitoring).

To convert from `bytes` to `gigabits` we need to divide and multiply as `(1000 / 1000 / 1000) * 8`. Let me explain in detail.

```
1000 bits = 1 kilobits
1000 kilobits = 1 megabits
1000 megabits = 1 gigabits
1 byte = 8 bits
```

To get Total Network in `Gbps` we need to `((NetworkIn + NetworkOut) / 300) / 0.008`.

```
m1 = NetworkIn - Sum
m2 = NetworkOut - Sum
Expression: (((((m1+m2)/300)/1000)/1000)/1000)*8
```